# Can't display my database on array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Ok thanks to all of u guys for your answers.

I've made some changing but i still can't display my array ...

Look at what i've done :

```
$prog = array();
$i=0;


        while($row = $get_programmation->fetch_assoc()){
        $prog[$i] = $row;
                $i++;
        }

echo json_encode($prog);
```

I would have this a result like this : {"id":"0","artist":"xxxx", .... etc} and then use it in my iOS app to display what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `programmation`");
```

Backticks instead of single quotes

Also in here `$articles[] = $row;`

in `$row` variable you have to specify MySQL table column names which you have to insert into array, for instance `$row['id']`, etc...

**NOTE:** See [mysql_ deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) post too

Answer (score 0):

you can not use quotes in table name or field name but you can use backtick()

```
$get_programmation = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'programmation'");
```

should be:

```
$get_programmation = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `programmation`");
```

or

```
$get_programmation = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM programmation");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this `$get_programmation = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'programmation'");`

with this `$get_programmation = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM programmation");`

Then importantly change code in while loop as below

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_programmation)){
        array_push($articles, $row['yourcol1'],$row['yourcol2']);
    }
echo json_encode($articles);
```

$row is not actual array. You can get the value if it using your actual column name only. And here I have pushed it to the array in while loop to form as array.(Here I have mentioned only two column, You can take all your columns in such way.)

Comment: Based on your php version use mysqli_* or mysql_*

Comment: Don't forget to make the variable within single or quotes if the coloumn return string value.

Comment: Yes i had to use mysqli version, i've made the change :)